# How to generate PDF from HTML/CSS

Tags: php, pdf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convert HTML + CSS to PDF with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/391005/convert-html-css-to-pdf-with-php)

I was searching for a way to convert HTML to PDF, but all I found was very limited.

Comment: There are loads and loads of duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php+pdf+html if what's in them is too limited, there is no way to do what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are plenty of issues you need to address, which you have failed to do so. Does it need to support advanced table structures, css support etc. As a start you can look into [html2pdf](http://www.tufat.com/s_html2ps_html2pdf.htm) or a paid solution [PrinceXML](http://princexml.com/)

Answer (score 1):

If you can use printing, you may try using the FreePDF XP printer driver.
It uses GhostScript, so a library for it, if you want to do it programatically, may also do the trick.